# Default sizing of R console window upon opening it

Tags: r

When I open my default RGui (not R Studio or anything fancy), there will be a full-screen grey RGui window and a tiny white "R Console". How do I

**a)** Make it such that the "R Console" is maximized upon opening RGui.

**b)** Make it such that when I open RGui, it takes up a proportion of my full screen instead of my entire screen.

Comment: You can save the options from the `GUI preferences` in the `edit` menu

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When installing, you can select a HUD/GUI based option which will make it such that, upon opening, the white console takes up the entire RGui window, and the RGUI window is about 25% of the screen size. I forgot the option you select, but it was when you install the `.exe` and you're asked to choose between two HUD based options ... choose the other one ... Can't really explain but it's impossible to miss if you're paying attention.

Answer (score 4):

As it is almost impossible to Google for `R` related console topics, I eventually stumbled upon the solution by accident while trying to understand the content and usage of the *Rconsole* file.

The *Rconsole* file is found in: `${R_HOME}/etc/Rconsole`. It's settings are set as default by your choices, during the installation phase, but may contain many other options not elsewhere available. Unlike some of the other customized settings files, such as:

```
.RData
.Renviron
.Rhistory
.Rprofile
```

the `Rconsole` file is not "*dotted*". So you are best to copy the default from the path above, to your `R_USER` home directory and edit it there.

The key to set the R application window's default size, is to ensure you edit the MDI related sections, so that it reads something like:

```
...
#--------------------------------------
# Style
#--------------------------------------
# This can be 'yes' (for MDI) or 'no' (for SDI).
MDI = yes
...
# Dimension of MDI frame in pixels
# Format (w*h+xorg+yorg) or use -ve w and h for offsets from right bottom
# This will come up maximized if w==0
# MDIsize = 0*0+0+0
# MDIsize = 1000*800+100+0
MDIsize = -50*-50+50+50  # 50 pixels space all round

# The internal pager can displays help in a single window
# or in multiple windows (one for each topic)
# pagerstyle can be set to `singlewindow' or `multiplewindows'
pagerstyle = multiplewindows
...
```

Here it is `MDIsize` that set the default window size. If the first value therein is `0` then the window will become maximized.