# Open R console maximized (full-screen) when opening RData file

Tags: r, console

Slightly related to this question [Default sizing of R console window upon opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559813/default-sizing-of-r-console-window-upon-opening-it)

When I open directly the R console it maximizes automatically, however when I click on an RData file which opens up a console, the console is always centered-off the screen and never maximized. Is there a way that when I open an RData file I can have the R console maximized?

I am on Windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @not2qubit no I haven't and it's annoying, so for this and other reasons I switched to Rstudio.

Comment: I think I found a solution! Please see the linked question. You need to set `MDIsize = 0*0+0+0` in your `Rconsole` file. In your case I suspect you may need to change the default settings somewhere, and check wich file it is using for default. When opening an *.RData* file.

Comment: Try to run the example from [here](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/utils/html/Rconsole.html).